# M1 & M2 - Incorrect FedEx Rates (Out-of-Area Costly Surcharges Excluded)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, shipping-methods, fedex

ISSUE - M1 & M2 - Incorrect FedEx Rates (Out-of-Area Costly Surcharges Excluded)

Generate a FedEx rate within the Magento shopping cart in either version 1.9.x or 2.x for New Zealand post code 7482. Then generate a rate within FedEx shipping software for the Pegasus Bay Winery at 
263 Stockgrove Road, RD2
Amberley, Canterbury 7482
New Zealand

You will find the Out-of-Area (remote) surcharge of more than $40 is completely left out of the rate assessed in M1 and M2. After spending more than an hour on the phone with FedEx today, it appears Magento does not query for an update using the full address once entered into the cart. By querying only the post code, this FedEx rate is not properly assessed.

Also, for some reason, Magento uses WSDL version 10 for FedEx queries rather than the current version 24. Why?

Is there a solution to this or is this cause to report a bug?